# A occhio e croce

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

What are the origins of the expression "a occhio e croce" meaning "approximately"? Anything perhaps to do with the term "heads or tails" ("testa o croce")?

Comment: Ha qualcosa a che vedere con [questo](https://unestiuqualsevolamonistrol.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/20120717-creullenyataire-01.jpg?w=690)? Si tratta di uno strumento per misurare l'altezza degli alberi in modo approssimativo.

Comment: @Charo: questa ipotesi, in effetti, sarebbe abbastanza coerente con la traduzione tedesca _über den Daumen gepeilt_ (_"traguardato sul pollice"_) e con quella inglese _by rule of thumb_ (_"a regola/regolo/righello di pollice"_), in cui lo strumento è costituito dal pollice. Resterebbe però da trovare una conferma.

Comment: @WalterTross: Ho scoperto che in italiano questo strumento si chiama "la croce del boscaiolo": https://books.google.es/books?id=LDKI0TcAHgcC&pg=PA567&lpg=PA567&dq=%22croce+del+boscaiolo%22&source=bl&ots=J9jwna_bt5&sig=MfZcgN-o3Pgib6YbpGoCiQZtf18&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lEWiVfrVKcr1UqXfgagJ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22croce%20del%20boscaiolo%22&f=false

Comment: @WalterTross La "regola del pollice" o la "rule of thumb" per quanto ne so deriva dalla fisica e ha poco a che vedere con "a occhio e croce": si mette la mano distesa in modo tale che nel chiuderla questa mimi il moto rotatorio di un punto nello spazio, concorde con il vettore che lo descrive e con il punto di vista dell'osservatore, e di riflesso il pollice punta o verso il basso o verso l'alto; questo serve a stabilire la direzione del vettore risultante: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Moto_circolare.svg/350px-Moto_circolare.svg.png

Comment: @kos, quella che citi è più spesso chiamata the [_right hand rule_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) (_regola della mano destra_, in italiano), a  volte anche _Ørsted's rule (of thumb)_, ma questo uso è molto più recente dell'origine dell'[espressione](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb)

Comment: @WalterTross Quindi devo andare a ricercare il professore di fisica e spiegargli che potrebbe anche spiegare la stessa cosa usando un'accezione molto più nota? :) Quindi diresti, almeno per la versione inglese, ante 1820?

Comment: In spagnolo l'espressione con lo stesso significato è "a ojo de buen cubero", che letteralmente significa "a occhio di buon bottaio".

Comment: The term "by rule of thumb" is completely different than the "right hand rule". Il mio prof di chimica spiegava qualcosa come che quando uno sbagliava si prendeva una legnata sul pollice quindi il termine.

Comment: Cioè, l'espressione sembra essere legata al metodo usato da qualcuno che è molto abile misurando.

Comment: Forse hai ragione, sembra di sì.

Comment: @kos: almeno 1685, secondo [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is, for what's worth, what Carlo Lapucci says in his *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* (Garzanti-Vallardi, 1979):

> **Fare a *occhio* e croce**
>   Misurare, stimare a vista, all'ingrosso, alla peggio, con un'occhiata per lungo e una per traverso.
>
> [To measure, to estimate approximately, roughly, in the ballpark of, with a look along and one by the side.]

So this author apparently suggests that the “cross” refers to two different lines of sight to give a quick estimate.

Comment: È vero, la citazione ha valore discutibile, e lo dico io stesso, ma come mai il downvote?

Comment: Also the book *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* by Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015) supports this explanation: «Si riferisce a una misura che viene calcolata dando un'occhiata da sinistra a destra e dall'alto in basso, come a seguire la forma di una croce.»

Answer (score 6):

Deriva probabilmente dal gergo di antichi tessitori i quali, qualora vi fossero verificati degli errori di filatura, dovevano "ad occhio" rimettere i fili sfuggiti tesi a croce. E' riportato nel libro “[L’arte della seta in Firenze](http://archive.org/stream/lartedellasetai00garggoog/lartedellasetai00garggoog_djvu.txt)”, trattato del secolo XV con dialoghi raccolti da Girolamo Gargiolli per i tipi di Barbera nel 1868.

Probably it comes from the jargon of ancient weavers who, if there were filature errors, had, in an approximately way,  put the theads escaped tight and cross. It's reported in the book "The Art of Silk in Florence" treaty of the century XV with dialogues collected by Girolamo Gargiolli for the types of Barbera in 1868.

Comment: Il trattato “L’arte della seta in Firenze”, come scritto nella risposta. Sto facendo una ricerca più approfondita al riguardo.

Comment: @Charo Non sono d'accordo. Ad occhio e croce significa qualcosa di approssimativo. E nel compiere tale operazione si faceva necessariamente qualcosa di poco preciso.

Comment: @Charo - ad occhio e croce non si usa solo in riferimento a delle misure ( peso, lunghezza etc. ) puoi anche dire: *a occhio e croce mio nonno non è più in grado di vivere da solo, avrà bisogno di una badante!!*

Comment: @MarcoCantarini - si fa riferimento anche qui, https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_oculum , al gergo degli antichi tessitori. Sarebbe interessante se tu trovassi altri riferimenti.

Comment: @Charo ^78 dialogo IV.

Comment: Anche qui: A occhio e croce
Il modo di dire “a occhio e croce” deriva dal mondo dei tessitori come riportato ne “L’arte della seta in Firenze”, ***trattato del secolo XV con dialoghi raccolti da Girolamo Gargiolli per i tipi di Barbera nel 1868*** Il volume, come già detto in un mio precedente post (19 marzo 2009), è diviso in due parti, la prima riguarda il testo dell’antico trattato e la seconda è un commento, in forma dialogica, alle varie operazioni descritte nel suddetto da parte di competenti artigiani dell’arte della seta.
https://tetimusmeci.wordpress.com/tag/etimologia/

Comment: @Charo -   *Accademia della Crusca*: 
Definiz: §. XVIII. ***A occhio, e croce***, posto avverbialm. ***Alla grossa, Senza minuta considerazione.***  Lat. incuriose, crassius. Gr. προπετῶς, παχειμερέστερον.
Esempio: Buon. Fier. 4. 5. 20. ***Calculata A occhio, e croce*** la valuta loro Ve ne farò poi la distribuzione ec. Che similmente a occhio, e croce spesso Valutate anche voi le mercanzíe. http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=OCCHIO&rewrite=1